# Spree 2.1.0. How to avoid a shipment method choosing when creating an order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have no need to choose a shipment method because it is the only one. A shipment price still depends on address location. How to avoid a shipment method choosing when creating an order ?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (found here: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html#modifying-the-checkout-flow), you can change the checkout flow like this:

```
checkout_flow do
  go_to_state :payment
  go_to_state :complete
end
```

So I think your code should look something like this:

```
Spree::Order.checkout_flow do
  go_to_state :address
  #go_to_state :delivery <= I've commented this line.
  go_to_state :payment, if: ->(order) {
    order.update_totals
    order.payment_required?
  }
  go_to_state :confirm, if: ->(order) { order.confirmation_required? }
  go_to_state :complete
  remove_transition from: :delivery, to: :confirm
end
```

You can find the checkout_flow you're overwriting here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-1-stable/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L8

Maybe you can remove the step like this:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  remove_checkout_step :delivery
end
```

That should get you in the right direction.